# After migrating Eclipse project from Windows to Ubuntu, Eclipse shows "cannot be resolved" compilation errors over all place

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, compiler-errors, cannot-find-symbol

I had created a website in eclipse using tomcat as a server on windows 7 and it was working very fine. But now i have migrated from windows to ubuntu. I have installed java and it is working very well. But my eclipse is displaying error on each and every statement (this cannot be resolved). Please suggest how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your eclipse is referring to JRE associated with windows path. Simply go to

> Project Setting -> Java Build Path -> Edit/re-add JRE

wth correct path for your ubuntu system